# Dot in Classpath Declaration

Tags: java, classpath

I read that basically in order to activate the searching function in the current folder by using the command line `javac -cp` it's mandatory to specify a dot(.) as follows `javac -cp . File.java`.
I noticed that if I omit the dot it works anyway. Has is it changed perhaps in the latest Java 7 updgrade?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.` stands for "current directory". Try running the command from another directory or with necessary jars outside of it and you should see the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the Java classpath will always contain the current folder as well as any jar files in `./lib/` even when you specify and empty classpath `javac -cp File.java`

I think it has been this way since Java 5.